# std::fill_n of rvalues, does it only support filling by copy?

Tags: c++

given an `std::vector` of `std::futures`

```
std::vector<std::future<void>> futures;
```

how come `std::fill_n` complains about me calling the copy constructor when I'm passing an rvalue:

```
std::fill_n(std::back_inserter(futures), 10, std::async([]{ std::cout << "yo\n"; }));

error: use of deleted function future(const future&)
```

I mean, doesn't `fill_n` receive an xvalue? If it doesn't, why not?

Comment: Well what else did you expect? The input to be moved over and over again? How would that work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::fill_n` makes copies of the given object passed as third argument but the third argument is a future object which is not copyable, as it doesn't make sense to copy future. Hence the error.

It seems you need this:

```
std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(futures), 
                10, 
               []{  return std::async([]{ std::cout << "yo\n"; }); });
```

Answer (score 5):

The interface of [`std::fill_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill_n) is:

```
template< class OutputIt, class Size, class T >
OutputIt fill_n( OutputIt first, Size count, const T& value );
```

It then copies `value` `count` times. That's why you're getting your error. Although, even if it moved, `fill_n` wouldn't make sense as a choice of function... you'd be moving from the same `future` 10 times, so you'd end up with one valid `future` and 9 empty ones? What would the point of that be?